# SQL a value belong to set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want something like this:

```
SELECT F01,F02,F03,F04
 FROM TABLE1
 WHERE TABLE1.F01 "Is one of the values from" (SELECT F01 FROM TABLE2 
          WHERE TABLE2.F06 = '5');
```

Is even such a thing possible in SQL? Also I am using Microsoft SQL server 2008.

Comment: yes, use `IN`. Unless I misunderstood something...

Comment: true, It's been a while since I code in SQL haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply replace "Is one of the values from"  with  IN, you are done.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible.  You just need to use the [IN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) keyword, like this:

```
SELECT F01,F02,F03,F04
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TABLE1.F01 IN (SELECT F01 FROM TABLE2 
                    WHERE TABLE2.F06 = '5');
```